# It is possible to pre load a lazy loaded module in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I know that when a app has a lot of parts and components it is good to separate them into lazy loaded modules so the user does see the app home page fast.

The thing is I have notice that the navigation to an lazy loaded module's component shows some lag between the user interaction (click in the button/menu) and when the component is show (compared with a non lazy loaded component).

Is there a way to pre load a lazy loaded module manually? so lets say the user sees the home screen and if nothing is done in 3 seconds then load some of my critical app modules in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `preload` strategy just for one module by setting the `data: { preload: true }`  instead of all the modules using `PreloadAllModules`.

```
{
  path: 'crisis-center',
  loadChildren: () => import('./crisis-center/crisis-center.module').then(mod => mod.CrisisCenterModule),
  data: { preload: true }
},
```

Comment: This looks good. I could probably do the same when the `crisis-center` module is loaded (load the children modules I mean). Do not I?

Comment: BTW, I've never heard of a `data.preload: true` option. Are you sure it was working before? The more you live the more you learn. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use **preloadingStrategy**

You have to add it like this:

`RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy : PreloadAllModules } )`

Example:

`import { RouterModule, Routes, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';`

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'employees', loadChildren: './employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy : PreloadAllModules } )],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is a good [Article](https://medium.com/@muthudevendra/angular-custom-preloading-strategy-32abe99944f8)